# Удалил rfremix-relese при попытке обновления

Tags: linux, fedora

Сегодня хотел обновить Руссиан Федора Ремикс (RFRemix) 28->29.

dnf upgrade выдал сообщение о конфликте в пакете rfremix-release-2.ххххххх
Немного посомневался, но решил что это модуль именно ремикса (скорее всего репозиторий) я решил его снести, а потом после обновления поставить (раньше так делал с другими конфликтными пакетами) Он потащил за собой десяток-другой зависимостей. Но так как объем не превышал пару десятков Мб, я опять решил, что ничего критического он за собой не потащит. А зря! В процессе удаления экран вывалился в консоль. После перезагрузки попадаю в emergency mode.
Есть ли способ восстановить систему? Так не хочется заново все ставить.

Если нужно могу приложить системный журнал.

ПС. Вот сейчас думаю, не было ли в зависимостях lvm-*. Если да, то сглупил я конкретно.