# Failed to start Disk Manager, System Logined service, etc

Tags: linux, fedora

Связано с темой [Удалил rfremix-relese при попытке обновления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/900644/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bb-rfremix-relese-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Мне удалось добиться следующего:

Я скачал с другой ОС некоторые файлы: репозитории типа fedora-release и тому  подобное, установил их, также сделал:

```
dnf install anaconda
```

как и предполагалось она потребовала много зависимостей включая lmv. После установки перегрузил систему, загрузка пошла, но... так и не закончилась - система висла на этом экране. Более детальный анализ показал, что выводятся сообщения о невозможности загрузить некоторые сервисы: Disk Manager, System Logined service и многие другие. Я так понимаю, что причина в этом.

**SELinux отключён**, по крайней мере в файле конфига стоит disabled 
Да, если важно: RFRemix 64 bit, 28 version

Comment: По-моему - проще переустановить. Особенно, если у тебя не потёрся `/etc` и `/home` на отдельном разделе.

Comment: @donRumata, /home на отдельном, а что /etc можно тоже на отдельный как-то и не думал. Кстати, уже переустановил.

Comment: Не, `/etc` хранить в корне. А вот `/home` лучше на отдельный. Спасает от вот такого "плохо обновился", "криво встали обновы" и прочее. Сносишь корень, ставишь всё с нуля, а закладки в браузере и обои на рабочем столе на месте. Ну если login и pass старые воткнёшь.